# Windows batch file force return error level 1 when it finds a missing file

Tags: batch-file

I am new to command scripting.

I am able to find and list out the missing files from a folder into an output file using the below code.

Please let me know how can i force to get an error code 1 when there is a missing file.

Thanks

```
@echooff
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "N:\opasdata\d110001\medias\images"
set found=false
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (listimagescopy.txt) do (
  for /r %%x in (%%a) do (
    if exist "%%a" set found=true
  )

  if "!found!"=="false" echo %%a >>"V:\Current Library\notfound.txt"
  set found=false
)

ECHO Files are Available
EXIT /B 0

:END
ECHO Files are not Available
EXIT /B 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echooff
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    pushd "N:\opasdata\d110001\medias\images"

    set "missingFiles=0"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (listimagescopy.txt) do (
        dir /s /b /a-d "%%a" >nul 2>nul || (
            echo %%a >> "V:\Current Library\notfound.txt"
            set "missingFiles=1"
        )
    )

    if %missingFiles%==0 (
        echo Files are available
    ) else (
        echo Files are not available
    )

    popd & endlocal & exit /b %missingFiles%
```